# Why is my VBA's vlookup returning error 2042 in one computer but working correctly in another?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, range, vlookup

I'm reaching out to request help with a vlookup in VBA which works in the computer I created the script on but doesn't in a different one despite having no changes. The task at hand is quite simple:

1. Populate a column with today's date
2. Store this date in a variable.
3. Find the matching week for this date and print it in an adjacent column.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub macro1()

    Dim source As Range
    Dim theval As Date
       
    'Source is a calendar table where the value being looked for is in col. C and its corresponding week in col. H         
    Set source = Workbooks("Catalogo Global.xlsx").Sheets(3).Range("C2:H731")
    
    'Populate entire column with today's date:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Q2:Q10").Formula = "=TODAY()"
    

    theval = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Q2").Value
    
    '*** HERE IS THE PROBLEM:Adding .value after "source" was what made the original code work but is now returning error 2042 in the current computer
    LookedValue = Application.VLookup(theval, source.Value, 6, False)

End Sub
```

As you'll notice, it was the addition of the method `.value` in the last line which did the trick in the first computer but isn't working in this new one.

And in case you're wondering, the calendar source table is retrieved by user input so the problem can't be attributed to a missing source to compare against.

1. I've alredy tried removing the `.value` method and error 2042 persists.
2. I've tested the `source` range to ensure it isn't empty.
3. And I've also made sure that **the value actually exists** in the source table and both data types are '7' for Date so its not a matter of handling for different possible values since I'm certain already that a match exists.
4. And last but not least, **manually performing the vlookup** in the worksheet correctly finds matches and returns no error.

Comment: Could it be related to the computers' system date settings?

Comment: Try `.value2` as that should ignore system date settings.

Comment: Probably, now that you mention it. The original computer has US formatting and this current one is "dd/mm/yyyy". Still data types match and source table and vlookup value have same formatting, wouldn't this supercede the system's formatting? Considering it is homologous at this stage now.

Comment: I'm not sure... but `.value2` will lookup the numerical date value, test it and let me know!

Comment: `.value2` unfortunately didn't work ;(

Comment: Oh, you should feed VLookup a range. Change `source.Value2` to just `source`

Comment: The date may be saved as a text string in one and a number in the other, which would make it not see them as matches.

Comment: @CameronCritchlow had no luck with feeding it a range either, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Scott Craner I've checked both with VarType() and both are 7 haha its kind of annoying how a couple of lines of relatively simple code are taking me so long to figure out.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using .value here. VLookup should take range arguments, to stay consistent with how you would use it normally (for what you are looking up, and for where you are looking up). Otherwise - well, it gets into the realm of "for experts only". But if you are going to be looking up a `.Value` then I guess you should provide an array of `.Values`, and ditto if you are looking up `.Value2s` then you should probably provide a `.Value2`. Still, I would be happy to have a play with it ... if you can show some sample data it would help.

Comment: @topsail Hi thank you for your input! At this stage I don't know if it already is an issue with my pc for I've tried those 3 alternatives you mention (range, value, value2) and still, they all continue returning error 2042.

Comment: I want to make sure I've pointed out that a range argument is preferable (in my opinion) for both `theval` and `source`

Comment: @topsail regarding the sample data, is there a way I can upload my excel here? Or can you recommend me a way to share such sample?

Comment: @topsail I get it now! You're right! I set theval as a range and assigned it the first cell! It works!!!! Thank you very much you don't know how much I appreciate it!

Comment: Honestly, I always have trouble getting WS.Functions like Match and VLookup to work consistently in VBA scripts. What I have done routinely in the past is is use a UDF I made called `Matching()`. ( I can share if you want ), or you can use the `Range.Find`

Comment: @CameronCritchlow same here, you said the magic word: their behaviour is inconsistent and somewhat unpredictable. I'd really appreciate if you could share it! Perhaps it would spare me several future headaches.

Comment: error 2042 means the value you are searching for was not found in the first column of the range you are searching in.  There can be many reasons for that.  Without more details of your data we can only speculate

Comment: Okay, I added it. Might help... Otherwise I would try `Range().find... with .Offset` instead of VLookup

Comment: @chrisneilsen Hi Chris! As I mention at the bottom of the post I made sure that the value exists and that the range I'm looking in includes it and isn't empty. What made the trick to solve the problem in this instance was topsail's recommendation to use both parameters to the vlookup as Range objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here:, I'd change the Val datatype to date:

```
Option Explicit
Function Matching(RG As Range, Val As Variant, Optional R_Order As Boolean)
    
    ' RG:
    ' - The range to search, must be one dimentional.
    '
    ' Val:
    ' - Value to find, sometimes "Variant" data type
    '   can cause issues, if you're looking for a
    '   specific data type, change "Val" to that data
    '   type.
    '
    ' R_Order: (Reverse Order)
    ' - If set to true, will return last item in list
    '   rather than first.
    
    ' > Var:
    Dim RGarray
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    RGarray = RG
    
    ' > Flip Boolean, not required, but easier to follow.
    R_Order = Not R_Order
    
    ' > Error handling
    On Error GoTo ERRORHAND
    
    ' > Check Cell Count
    If RG.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Matching = 0
        Debug.Print "Error: " & RG.Address
        Debug.Print " -> Only one cell."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' > Check Array is 1 Dimentional
    If UBound(RGarray, 1) > 1 And UBound(RGarray, 2) > 1 Then
        Matching = 0
        Debug.Print "Error: " & RG.Address
        Debug.Print " -> Select only one col OR row, not both."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' > Find Val operation
    For X = 1 To UBound(RGarray, 2)
        For Y = 1 To UBound(RGarray, 1)
            If RGarray(Y, X) = Val Then
                Matching = Y + X - 1
                If R_Order = True Then Exit Function
            End If
        Next Y
    Next X
    
    Matching = 0
    Debug.Print "Not Found in: " & RG.Address
    Debug.Print " -> " & Val
    
Exit Function
ERRORHAND:
Debug.Print "Error: " & RG.Address
Debug.Print " -> Unknown Error"
On Error GoTo 0
Err.Clear
End Function
```

Call like:

- `Debug.Print Matching(Selection, 2)` or,
- `Debug.Print Matching(Range("A1:A10"), "Pencil", True)` or,
- `Debug.Print Matching(MyRange, MyDate)`

Comment: Much obliged! I'm looking into it as we speak. I'm sure it'll come in handy!